# Django1.11 - URLconf does not appear to have any patterns

Tags: python, django

I'm a new user of django and i have some difficulties.
I follow a Django 1.8 tutorial and i have Django1.11. the problem is about urls.py files & patterns

Here my code, blog/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpattern = [
   url(r'^accueil/$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

first/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url include

urlpattern = [
   url(r'^blog/', include('blog/urls')),
]
```

And when i use runserver command, it display :

```
URLconf '<module 'blog.urls'>'does not appear to have any patterns in it
```

I read somewhere that patterns are removed since 1.10 and it's an old syntax now but i don't found the solution.

Any idea ?

Comment: Note that the "patterns" that was removed is the actual function [`patterns()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urls/#patterns). The concept of url patterns still exists, but uses a plain list instead, like you're already doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django 1.11 is not released. You should use the actual released version, 1.10. Also, you should use the actual tutorial for your version.

However, the problem is that both of your files should define `urlpatterns` with an s, not `urlpattern`.

Comment: indeed, i did a mistake, i now have another problem but i'll check myself the solution before ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think your need this page.[URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/)

Your code is fault, I think your need to change it:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^accueil/$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```